# What caused the Roman phallus symbol to fall out of use?

Tags: ancient-rome, religion

In a lot of old Roman artifacts from statues to jewelry to even oil lamps,
The [phallus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phallus#Classical_antiquity) is often a prominent feature. From what I gather, it was used as symbol of power and protection.

However, when Christianity became prominent the phallus symbol was seemingly removed from the public. What was the reason for this? Was it simply the need to distance oneself from anything from the old religion and so the phallus was branded sinful needing to be removed or where there other reasons?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I don't think that there can be a definitive answer, but consider that Christianity is basically opposed to sex - e.g. original sin, the virgin birth, celibate clergy, &c - so they would be unlikely to use any explicitly sexual symbol.

Comment: @jamesqf - My hunch is roughly the same. I'm not seeing any instances of it after Constantine, and you're right that that particular religion historically has not exactly been sex-positive. If the hunch is right though, I'd think there might be historical artifacts of it to be found. Diatribes against those specific symbols from 3rd-4th century clerics and that kind of thing.

Comment: Read the City of God from St Augustine, the Christians were not the only ones to consider some pagans rites obscene, promiscuous and generally prejudicial to individuals and to society as a whole. And dick drawings were not the worst problem of these rites...

Comment: besides, as the history of St Valentine shows, the church was totally not against but in favor of sex... inside marriage.

Comment: @Luiz: Not so, not then, not now.  The basic idea is that sex is only for procreation, and thus is necessary but inherently shameful.  Likewise just about anything to do with naked human bodies.  Some even have sex while clothed.

Comment: @jamesqf people can do weird things and overprotect, but custom is not doctrine. Doctrinally when it is said that the procreative purpose is more important than the unitive purpose, it is because the 1st is absolutely needed for the existence of humanity, it does not mean the 2nd is not important. As JPII said in the Denver stadium: "Sex is good... (pause, audience gasps) ... within marriage (audience silences, deep silence)" Remember whatever is not a sin, it is within legitimate human liberty, thus is good, more or less good, but not bad, regardless of how much private/hidden it should be.

Comment: @Luiz: You seem to be having logic problems.  You quote someone (I assume JPII is the recent Catholic pope?) to support your claim that Christianity isn't anti-sex, when what he said was explicitly anti-sex.

Comment: @Luiz: And if you are indeed quoting the Catholic Pope John Paul II, remember that he - like every other Catholic priest - had sworn a vow of celibacy.  Hard to get more anti-sex than that - or so I thought, until I looked up Christian self-castration, and found sects like the Skoptsy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skoptsy

Comment: @jamesqf When something is offered to God, or when one abdicates of something as a vow, sacrifice or penance, it must be a good thing on itself (see the sacrifice of Cain and Abel). A priest's vow to not marry (not having sex comes as consequence) only makes sense if marriage is good - abdicating of sin is an obligation, no merit. I don't care about crazy sects, easy to see it is  doctrinally off ( e.g. Origen in ancient times, nobody in the church said he was right about castrating himself ). If counting crazy sects, some cathars were against marriage and human reproduction, not the Church.

Comment: @Luiz: Not having sex is NOT a consequence of not marrying :-)  As for "sin", you keep supporting my point with your own words.  Why would it be a "sin" if Christianity didn't view sex as sinful?

Comment: Few things are intrinsically bad or good (always sinful or good regardless of circumstances), most depend on circumstances. Marriage is where sex is good. As for the importance of family and marriage, it is a long story, but many societies today don't even have enough children to keep themselves in existence (besides supporting the children with a caring family and keeping liberty). If not being able to remain in existence is not a fail, what is?